# Android lollipop UI in KitKat

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I would like to have android l ui on it even for KitKat. I have seen apps like inbox and pushbullet to use this such as the rotation of the circle button and the status bar recolor. How do they do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) to maintain backwards compatibility.

According to the documentation:

> The v7 Support Libraries r21 and above includes the following material
>   design features:
>
> - Material design styles for some system widgets when you apply one of
>     the Theme.AppCompat themes.
> - Color palette theme attributes in the Theme.AppCompat themes.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: I tried that but I could only get the action bar to work. Nothing else. Any idea